# Direct Limit of Grassmannians

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory, grassmannian

Let $X$ be a topological space and $G_n(\mathbb{C}^m)$ be the space of vector subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^m$ of codimension $n$.

Let $G_n(\mathbb{C}^\infty):=\bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty}G_n(\mathbb{C}^m)$ using the natural inclusion $$G_n(\mathbb{C}^m)\hookrightarrow G_n(\mathbb{C}^{m+1})$$

**Question**: Is it true that $$ \lim_\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{m} [X\to G_n(\mathbb{C}^m)] \stackrel{(1)}{=} [X\to G_n(\mathbb{C^\mathbb{\infty}})]\stackrel{(2)}{=}[X\to G_n(\mathcal{H})]$$

Where the square brackets denote homotopy classes, $\lim_\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{m}$ denotes the "direct limit", and $\mathcal{H}$ is any infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space? Is the first expression on the left-hand side called "*stable-homotopy*", which is weaker than homotopy?

**Question:** How to relate the (for instance, de Rham) cohomologies or the Chern classes of $G_n(\mathcal{H})$, $G_n(\mathbb{C^\mathbb{\infty}})$, and $G_n(\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{m})$ for some $m$?

Comment: No, you're not doing anything involving stable homotopy yet. As written I think you need some compactness hypotheses on $X$ for this to be true.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, what about definition 2.20 on page 12 here: http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~usher/vbnotes.pdf ?

Comment: This is bad terminology. The "stable" in "stable vector bundle" is not the same as the "stable" in "stable homotopy"; they refer to two different kinds of stabilization (one with respect to adding trivial bundles, and one with respect to suspension).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true if $X$ is compact. It's not true for all paracompact spaces; I don't know if there's anything more you can say but for when $X$ is compact. (To see the second sentence, take $X = \Bbb{CP}^\infty$, $n=1$, and you get by looking at cohomology that every map $X \to \Bbb{CP}^k$ induces the zero map on cohomology; in particular there is no $k$ such that the identity map $X \to X$ factors through a map $\Bbb{CP}^\infty \to \Bbb{CP}^k$.)

When $X$ is compact, then note that every compact subset of $G_n(\Bbb C^\infty)$ is contained in one of the $G_n(\Bbb C^m)$s. So in particular the image of $X$ is, and your map (1) is surjective. But it's also injective, by the same logic applied to $X \times I$.

Now, because *simplices* and *spheres* are compact, similar logic implies $H_k(G_n(\Bbb C^\infty)) = \lim H_k(G_n(\Bbb C^m))$, and similarly with $\pi_k$ and $H^k$.

(I can't quite answer the de Rham question because I don't know what the de Rham cohomology of $G_n(\Bbb C^\infty)$ even means, given that it's not a finite-dimensional manifold.)